# 0 test classes found in package 'drawable' Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I find an issue when running my project in android studio what i see when i try to run is

```
 0 test classes found in package 'drawable'

 Process finished with exit code -1
 Empty test suite.
```

Though I have searched for this issue I couldn't find a solution I even tried to invalidate cache and restart the project but still it doesn't works. This issue is only being caused for only this particular project however for a new project i make everything works smooth.

My gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jiit.minor2.shubhamjoshi.human"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')
}
```

My project structure

[image: My project structure]

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Because it's only happening in this project, we need some more info about the project. show project directory for example. Also gradle configs

Comment: @th3pat3l I have added the project structure and gradle config

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your project. This is happening because you are trying to run drawable in app. From the drop down select app and then run. It will be OK.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. I wonder how this happened. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

[image: App Configuration]

It's not erroring just misconfigurations. Just select the app and then run.
It will be OK.

Comment: And if you don't see the menu, use alt + shift + f10 and select run

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same error but because my unit-test files were not in the `src/test/java` directory (used to be fine in there).

Moving the test class files out of their local source directory and into the test one solved it (including a small amount of refactoring to import the classes that required testing).

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio's android-tests (not unit-tests), run in bash:

```
./gradlew :createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport --continue
```

Which shows actual problem, instead of just not found.

> For me actual error was:
>
> ```
> error: class ActivitySignInTest is public, should be declared in a file named ActivitySignInTest.java
> ```